# iOS MapKit Walking directions to point

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am adding a map component to my iOS app and I would like to be able to show the user their current location and a path to a destination location (both using GPS coordinates).  I have found a lot of sample apps online that do this but what I want to add is the direction they should be facing at the final point.

I thought that I might do this by adding a third point and have line drawn from the destination to the third point show direction but I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you have working so far?  It's not clear why you need a "third point".  Do you just need to calculate the compass heading in degrees from user location to destination or you want to actually draw a straight line from user location to destination?

Comment: I would like the user to know which direction they should face when they arrive at the point.